# What is the difference between MyType and typeof(MyType)?

Tags: c#, types

There's `enum` type `MyEnum`

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    foo,
    bar
}
```

I iterate through its values, which requires me to get the type of `MyEnum`

```
foreach (MyEnum enumEntry in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)))
{
   Console.WriteLine(enumEntry);// foo bar
}
```

The question is, `typeof(MyEnum)` supposedly returns the reference to the type of `MyEnum`, but isn't `MyEnum` already a type name like `string`, `int` etc? Why can't I do it without `typeof` like this:

```
foreach (MyEnum enumEntry in Enum.GetValues(MyEnum))
{
   Console.WriteLine(enumEntry);
}
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use the `Enum.GetValues(MyEnum)`. With `typeof()` you are retrieving a Type instance which presents the reflection type of that class.

Comment: AFAIK, only typeof or GetType can return types. How would compiler distinguish int.MaxValue, for example? it can be a public const value of int, or its Type object.

Comment: although this constructions looks really weird, not sure why there is still no generic version. so we could have something like MyEnum.GetValues()

Comment: Not really clear what kind of answer you are looking for... Do you need someone to comb through the C# specification to chain the reasoning for you? Are you suggesting a new C# feature? Are you asking why this particular syntax you like is not implemented? Something else? (So far the question is roughly the same as "Why `+;` is invalid C# code, I don't like it")

Comment: `Enum.GetValues(Type)` predates generics. There is a new overload that takes a generic parameter. The `typeof` operator obtains the `System.Type` instance for a type not the actual instance itself

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't understand how it works. In my understanding MyEnum and typeof(MyEnum) reference the same thing, but they evidently don't. What theoretical knowledge am I missing?

Comment: One is a description of your enum (typeof), the other is your enum. Its like saying oh I have seen your facebook page, I have met you. the facebook page isn't you! `typeof(enum) != enum` They are completely different things

Comment: [typeof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#typeof-operator): "The typeof operator obtains the `System.Type` instance for a type. The argument to the typeof operator must be the **name** of a type or a type parameter".

Answer (score 1):

> The question is, typeof(MyEnum) supposedly returns the reference to
> the type of MyEnum

First, your supposition is not correct, as there is a difference between the reference of type `T` and a instance type of a Type `T`. According to Microsoft documentation:

> The typeof operator obtains the System.Type **instance** for a type. The
> argument to the typeof operator must be the name of a type or a type
> parameter.

The `typeof` is an operator keyword which is used to get a type at the compile-time. Or in other words, this operator is used to get the System.`Type` object for a type. This operator takes the Type itself as an argument and returns the marked type of the argument.

> Why can't I do it without typeof like this `Enum.GetValues(MyEnum)`

The answer to that is barely related to the CLS *([Common Language Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/common-type-system#common-language-specification))*, your syntax is not valid and not supported (at least for now), currently the only way to work with types in a way semilar to what you mentioned is  by using a generic method like follows

```
Enum.GetValues<MyEnum>()
```

but of course, in this scenario, there is no generic overload for the `Enum.GetValues` method.

Comment: So, as I understand it, the name of a type, like `int` just refers to a marker somewhere in the memory, that indicates that certain 4 bytes of data are here to store a not-fractional number. And when we call typeof(int) then, paraphrasing, it returns an object with properties of the type like: `Name = "int" AmountOfBytes = 4 StoredDataType = "Numeric"` is it roughly how it is?

Comment: yes that's correct, except that the `Type` instance returns a set of information related to the type itself (is it a class, interface? is it public, internal, private? what's the assembly containing this type? ...etc. And other dozens of properties and methods used primarily in `Reflexion` to access that type information at runtime.